# Jenkins ANT script fails in the middle of running

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, jenkins, phpunit

I have a bunch of PHPUnit tests that I invoke with ANT in jenkins. All of a sudden

```
[exec] ...............................................................  63 / 644 (  9%)
[exec] ............................................................... 126 / 644 ( 19%)
[exec] ............................................................... 189 / 644 ( 29%)
[exec] ............................................................... 252 / 644 ( 39%)
[exec] ............................................................... 315 / 644 ( 48%)
[exec] .............................................................

BUILD FAILED
/etc/jenkins/build.xml:188: exec returned: 139

Total time: 57 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
```

Funny thing is that when I manually run the tests, everything runs (at the very least) ie: goes to 100%.

I already specify Jenkins to use the ant binary from

```
which ant
```

in Jenkin's config menu and force this particular build to use it.

None of this makes sense to me because earlier today the build was succeeding. This just started to happen a few days ago and I resolved it by restarting the machine but I really want to figure out why this spontaneously happens.

Comment: Does it always fail on the same test? You can add `-v` to the list of Ant targets in Jenkins to get verbose output.

Comment: Added `-v` to the list of targets, nothing useful in console output.

Comment: Sometimes the script fails out at 38%, sometimes at 48%...but even if there is code in an invoked test causing the ANT Invoke to fail how would I debug that? I don't think that it's any of the test code because phpunit would throw an error, right?

Answer (score 1):

Does it fail only on the Jenkins server, or does it fail on development machines too? What command is failing?

Exit code 139 is a segmentation violation. You'll have to determine what's failing.

- Since you're using Jenkins, and your using PHP and your using `<exec>` why not try to do the tests outside of  Ant? Jenkins can run commands as part of the build process. That will eliminate Ant as a possible cause.
- Try playing around with `<exec>` settings. Setting `spawn` to true will spawn a subshell that won't have the memory limit that running an `exec` in Java would have. Running out of memory could be causing the segmentation faults.

Comment: where do I add the spawn option? directly in `<exec executable="..." ...>` ...? When I add `spawn="true"` I get `You have used an attribute or nested element which is not compatible with spawn`

Comment: And it works on dev machines, so I'm pretty sure it's just seg faulting when invoked with ANT

Comment: What version of Ant are you using? Look in the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html). It's the sixth parameter listed.

Comment: I meant to ask for example syntax for using that argument in a build.xml, sorry. And ant is 1.8.2

Comment: `<exec executable="foo.exe" spawn="true"> <arg value="bar/> </exec>`. Still, if this is Jenkins, run the phpunit command from the command line. You can run ant and then the command directly from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. For me it ended up in a problem with xdebug, which is needed for the codecoverage report. Loading xdebug via another php config file seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: How did you configure xdebug to avoid this?